# Getting errors in Android Project in eclipse even if there is no error in source code or xml

Tags: android, eclipse

Suddenly this time when I created a new project is showing me error. When we create a new project in eclipse its a Hello World Project which is set up. But that is also showing error, I checked my source code that was perfect. and xml is also perfect. I can't make out where is the actual error. 
I tried Clean up my project but that too dint worked. I event tried Build Automatically but that also dint worked.
I even checked my sdk path, then Right click on Project-> Properties-> Java Build Path to check whether src file is listed as a Source folder.
Following error was shown in console.

```
[2012-09-22 17:41:03 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: wrapper was not properly     loaded first
[2012-09-22 17:41:03 - HelloHi] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute     dex: wrapper was not properly loaded first
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just restart the eclipse and run the project. The error arises while installing a new target version. After completion of the installation it will get fix automatically.

Comment: you are welcome.
Its the suggestion suggested by another one overhere.
I would love to thank him.